# File not found when run project from browser

Tags: json, excel, servlets

I write a function to read data from excel file, then generate whole datas to JSON. When i test running as application, it works well. But when i call that function into Servlet class and using browser to run it, the file not found exception come. I put the excel file to root folder of my project and URI is the same. Is there any one have ever had same issue with me? and know how to fix it? Thank.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information here. Can you share the code of the function that is reading from the excel file?

Comment: Sorry, it is a private project, so i can't share the code. But i think the issue is not about that. I just use FileInputStream to get the uri of my excel file on the server, like this:

FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(fileURI));
   Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

Comment: _it is a private project, so i can't share the code_ - well, in such case, hire a (paid) consultant and make him to sign a Non Disclosure Agreement. You can't get help for free without sharing information (in this case the code and your project structure).

Comment: The problem is when app has been deployed to server, the location of project will be changed. I have found the solution to resolve this issue, thanks you guys.